# Unable to proxy sites or download Charles Proxy certificate to iPhone

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm attempting to use Charles Proxy with an iPhone X (software version 15.0.2) and a MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina 10.15.7). I've changed the network it was running on recently, and now I can't get it to work. I know that I have correctly changed the proxy settings on the iPhone to match the host and port of the Charles instance, but the proxy is not working correctly. Sites where I have enabled SSL Proxying are not loading on the phone due to an SSL handshake failure. To make matters worse, I deleted the original Trust Certificate thinking that reinstalling it would solve the problem, but when I attempt to visit https://chls.pro/ssl, the page never completely loads and I'm unable to download a new one. (Also, for reasons I can't explain, I can't seem to move a certificate onto the phone manually.) I'm sure the issue is with the iPhone because I was able to connect an Android phone to Charles which is behaving as expected. What can I do to fix the connection and regain access to the proxy?